# Is there a miniature handheld/lap acoustic piano? (not electronic)

Tags: piano, composition, improvisation

So as I understand it a piano works by the keys pulling strings that make hammers ring bells based on how hard you hit them. I would guess that would be quite a sophisticated instrument. I myself have a miniature electronic piano with 36 keys which is very useful for composing electronic music on the computer, both because it can be used to play computer software and also because it is a handy compositional tool compared to a big 88 key keyboard on a stand. Not only is the 36 key keyboard smaller due to its lessened number of notes, but it also has miniature keys. Granted those can be annoying to play, but it works to allow me to effectively play a "piano" in my lap. So my question is,

*IS THERE A MINIATURE LAP HELD KEYBOARD that is actually acoustic, using strings to ring bells?*

I am very interested in acoustic instruments and have a violin myself which is an amazing instrument to play compared to a synthesizer because of the amount of ways you can play it compared to a boring "press button to play note." And granted, modern MIDI software allows MIDI keyboard users to map many different effects to their keyboards. But I am specifically interested in the sounds of a genuine piano itself, specifically the tinkly noises of bells, which I don't believe can be truly appreciated prerecorded from a computer speaker. I want to actually generate the bell rings myself, like with a bonafide grand piano, but I want it to be in miniature. Even if that means the bells would necessarily be tiny. Now that I am writing all this up I am imagining that this lap-piano would have to have very short strings in order to fit in a lap, which I am reading would mean it has low sound quality - but that's okay. I don't mind it.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jack. We don't recommend equipment on this site, but I do highly recommend watching a video about how pianos work. They do not work by pulling strings, nor do they operate bells. There are keyboard instruments that operate bells -- celesta, carillon, and specialty pianos with "janissary" bells installed, and "toy pianos".